# Return a value from an ASP page

Tags: c#, asp.net

I've been given the assignment of creating an asp.net/c# page which could be opened from either another web app or a desktop app, take user inputs and return a value to the parent application. I'm familiar with the concept of calling a web service and returning a value, but not a model like this where there is some user interaction on the web component. How would I accomplish this?

Clarifications:

- THis page could be called from any other application, in multiple languages.
- Essentially what I'm looking for is a webservice with an interface.

Comment: So you basically need to take user input in child application and return it to parent application?

Answer (score 0):

Just reference the the child project from the parent project and communicate the user data with the child project implementation....